# How to fix escape characters appearing in response while using python requests lib?

Tags: python, json, encoding, python-requests

I'm making *HTTP requests*  with Python's `requests` library and seeing escape characters in response(error messages).

I mainly get back `\` or `\\` in response, but sometimes I get `\\\\`.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong:

```
http_response = requests.request(method, http_url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=http_headers)
message = "My error " + str(response.txt)
```

Result:
`'Details: {\"result\":[{\"message\":\"The provided sample doesn\\'t work as expected}]}'`

Expected output: **Without** `\` characters.

Comment: Can you print the `response.headers` ?

Comment: {'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; version=1.0', 'content-language': 'en-US'}

Answer (score 2):

I believe its because your loading the response from the request as text instead of a JSON (which is what it is). Try this:

```
import json
http_response = requests.request(method, http_url,data=json.dumps(body),headers=http_headers)
myResponseJson = http_response.json()
message = "My error " + str(myResponseJson)
```

Comment: No, doesn't help.

Comment: His suggestion produces the exact same output. I'm seeing the escape characters in the error messages which come from the API.

Comment: @pep8 can you give me the API your attempting to use so I can replicate the issue?

Comment: Nope, private API

Comment: :/ Then I have no idea what may be causing the issue. The response headers show that it is a JSON so that should be working. The only other thing you can try is accessing the response text and just doing a ```response.text.replace("/","").replace("//","")```

Comment: Even replacing doesn't help :(

Comment: Is there any way you can change the content-language to UTF-8 instead of en-US

Comment: Well, it's a response from an API I've no control over.I'm consuming the API - not writing it.

Comment: Well in that case, I have no idea what may be causing the error. You'll have to wait for someone else to give it a shot. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add below two key/value pairs to your existing headers and try

{
'content-type': 'application/json',
'accept': 'application/json'
}